# add TabHost inside a TabHost :cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment 5

Tags: android-fragments

I'm trying to create a TabHost in ListView in a TabHost, and I get the cast error.

```
enter code here  Process: com.example.vaidenv2, PID: 30623
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.vaidenv2.FQAGeneralFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:420)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:343)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:280)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:13406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3919)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3733)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3678)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:968)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Here is my code in Fragment,

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class FAQFragment extends Fragment{
FragmentTabHost mTabHost = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup    container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());

    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),
            android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("sub1").setIndicator("General"),
            FQAGeneralFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("sub2").setIndicator("Endor"),
            FQAEndorFragment.class, null);


    return mTabHost;
    }
}
```

Could someone help me to see how to solve this. And the library and package are all most recent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logcat error is pointing to **FQAGeneralFragment** as the error.
I do not know `FQAGeneralFragment` type. I suspect it is not **android.support.v4.app.Fragment** class type. I would think FQAGeneralFragment is defined in another Java file, and you need to import **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**.

Please check it out and have fun...

Comment: @Maggie, You may select my answer to be the best correct answer by clicking on the checkmark icon. Thanks. Since you're new to Stackoverflow (SO), pls read up on its tutorial @ http://stackoverflow.com/tour . You will gain reputation points and a badge for it.  Welcome to SO community and enjoy!